# Can i undo ALTER table in - MySQL?

Tags: mysql, alter

Don't know if it's possible, I Altered VARCHAR column to Decimal Type which i want to Rollback. Because it blended all floating values as integer. like 2.00 became 200. Is there any way to undo my last table Alteration? Please advise.

Comment: Your best bet is to restore a backup from before you ran the `ALTER` statement.

Comment: unfortunately i had not made any backup.

Comment: Sorry. The only course of action is to convert it back to VARCHAR and then manually fix the values. I understand that it may be impossible to know if 200 is 2.00 or 20.0 or 200. :(

Comment: "unfortunately i had not made any backup". Hopefully this will be a good lesson for the future to always back up your data before making changes. If you're writing an application it's also good practice to store your SQL scripts in source control so you've got a history of what you ran previously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't roll back `ALTER TABLE` statements.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html

> Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or **alter tables** or stored routines.

(emphasis mine)

As Chris Peters comments above, you can do the reverse `ALTER TABLE` operation, and then clean up your data using `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: This answer deserves more love ... I wasted a bunch of time trying to work out why my rollbacks were failing in a database migration tool before I found it.