# Why does a column created in a rolled back transaction exist after the transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions

If I create a column in a transaction which is rolled back, the column will still exist after the transaction, however, I would expect the column to not exist due to the rollback. The question is: what is the reason of this behavior?

MCVE:

```
create table test(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    foo text
);

insert into test(foo) values ('a'), ('b'), ('c');

start transaction;

alter table test add column bar text;

rollback;

desc test;
```

Comment: 'Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored routines.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks, this seems to answer the question. If you would convert your comment to an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i undo ALTER table in - MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957232/can-i-undo-alter-table-in-mysql)